# MVC3 JQuery modal dialog retains content on close and reopen

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a jquery modal which renders a partial view however when data is entered into the view, and closed (not saved, just close the dialog) the content is retained in the view. So, next time the modal is opened, it is the same as when it was closed first time around.

Is there a way of forcing the modal to render the original partial view or make it do this? I've not posted the Partial view content as it's just a simple form with fields on.

**View**

```
<div id="client-detail-modal" title="Add New Address">
    @Html.Partial("_Address", address)
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 $("#client-detail-modal").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 'auto',
            width: 600,
            position: ['middle', 20],
            buttons: {
                "Add Address": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $('#client-detail-modal').css('height', 'auto');
```

**Initiator**

```
  $("#client-detail-modal").dialog("open");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the partial view into the page it renders the html into your main dom. With jquery dialog it takes the partial view and shows it in a dialog. When you make changes you modify the original view. You should on dialog open event clear any old values or load defaults and on dialog close event save the new values. This way you can reuse the same dialog many times.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open
http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close

Look at this as an example and view source
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form
On close event they remove any old data and clear any errors

```
close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
```

Comment: I wasnt really thinking about this as I should be resetting the form on the save so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myModal')
    .on('hide.bs.modal',
        function() {
            $('#myModal').removeData();
        });
```

Insert this code on section Scripts on `*.cshtml.`
This will remove the data, and in the next time that you open it they will create a new.